# Second form loads in Debug mode but not when running from Executable

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, ilmerge

Okay I have an initial form called EvenSelector, Where the user selects an event.

When they press they Okay Button, it loads the next form which is called EventView.

Here is my code to load the next form:

```
var nextForm = new EventView(user);
nextForm.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
nextForm.Show();
```

The EventView takes a class called User which simply stores the user name and the event they selected.

When I run from Visual Studio, it works fine.  When I merge the program with its DLLs with ILMerge, the second form doesnt load.  The first one does, it looks all okay, but then the second one doesnt load up.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Use dotpeek or ilspy to decompile your merged library and check the code of this method.

Comment: @dlatikay I am not sure how to do that - but it doesnt seem to crash, at least, theres no error message - The form closes, windows thinks for a minute then nothing happens.

Comment: @dlatikay `EventSelector` closes, then its gone from Task Manager and windows thinks for like a second and then nothing more.

Comment: @dlatikay I've found the `Application and Services Logs` in the event viewer, but i cant see how to enable or find my app in there :(

Comment: @AccessDenied I've loaded dotPeek, and it just shows my code the same as VS.  How does that help?

Comment: its in "Windows Logs > Application". Search by timestamp if there's no indication of program name.